# Do the hat functions have compact support?

Tags: calculus, analysis

The definition of compact support is that a function is non-zero outside a compact set.

Consider the "hat functions"

$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ 1-x & 0 \leq x \leq 1  \end{cases} $$

This function is said to have compact support, but it is non-zero on the open interval $(-1,1) $.  Have I misunderstood compact support? Can I reconcile the definition with this example?

Answer (score 1):

To say it with your own words, the definition of compact support is *rather* that a function is *zero* outside a compact set (the contrary of what you wrote).

Here the hat function $\phi(\cdot)$ is zero outside the compact set $[-1,1]$.